# Place subfigures in L shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to place 3 figures plus some text; something like this:

[image: I want]

But so far I have only been able to get this:

[image: I get]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    ~\\[1cm]
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
            {\scriptsize $t=0$~s}.
            
            
            {\scriptsize $r=0$~m}.
            
            
            {\scriptsize $585$ macro-particles}.
            
            
            {\scriptsize $\overline{T} = 152.4$~K}.
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            width = \linewidth,
            ylabel near ticks, 
            yticklabel pos=right,
            ylabel = {\tiny Particle Density~[m$^{-3}$]},
            xtick=\empty,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 77162484572430.92,
            xmin = 0.03157490368073539,
            xmax = 0.03653007600471181,
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            ]
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            width = \linewidth,
            ytick=\empty,
            xlabel = {\tiny Probability Density},
            ymin = -217828.00503348646,
            ymax = 213540.67299828946,
            xmax = 1.1333435035653558e-05,
            xmin = 0,
            x dir = reverse,
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            ]
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.49\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            width = \linewidth,
            ylabel near ticks, 
            yticklabel pos=right,
            ylabel = {\tiny Speed~[m/s]},
            xlabel = {\tiny $z$~[m]},
            xmin = 0.03157490368073539,
            xmax = 0.03653007600471181,
            ymin = -217828.00503348646,
            ymax = 213540.67299828946,
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            ]
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So, the difference between what I get and what I want is: The three plots should form an L, and be all closer together. The text should be like a fourth figure, and the text centered. I have tried changing the optional placements [b,t,c], but I havent been able to get something like what I want.

Comment: Do you need them in subfigures? Otherwise you could just use group plots.

Comment: They don't need to be subfigures. It is just the only way I "knew" how to do it. Btw, in case it matters, I will but all the three figures and the text inside a \animateinline and update the data to make a gif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grouplot`s here. Then you can precisely fix the horizontal and vertical distance of the plots by setting `horizontal sep` and `vertical sep`.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A group plot}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,
     horizontal sep=1.2em,vertical sep=1.5em},
    xmin=0,height=4cm,width=5cm,no markers,
     ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
     yticklabel pos=right,
     xlabel style= {font=\tiny},
     ylabel near ticks, 
     ylabel style= {font=\tiny},     
    ]           
    \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot,alias=TL]
    \nextgroupplot[ylabel = {Particle Density~[m$^{-3}$]},
            xtick=\empty,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 77162484572430.92,
            xmin = 0.03157490368073539,
            xmax = 0.03653007600471181]
%           
    \nextgroupplot[
            ytick=\empty,
            xlabel = {Probability Density},
            ymin = -217828.00503348646,
            ymax = 213540.67299828946,
            xmax = 1.1333435035653558e-05,
            xmin = 0,
            x dir = reverse,
            ]
%
    \nextgroupplot[
            ylabel = {Speed~[m/s]},
            xlabel = {$z$~[m]},
            xmin = 0.03157490368073539,
            xmax = 0.03653007600471181,
            ymin = -217828.00503348646,
            ymax = 213540.67299828946,
        ]               
\end{groupplot}
\path (TL) node[align=left,font=\scriptsize]{$t=\SI{0}{\second}$\\[0.6em]
    $r=\SI{0}{\meter}$\\[0.6em]
    $585$ macro-particles\\[0.6em]
    $\overline{T} = \SI{152.4}{\kelvin}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will work with animations as well as (or even better than) subfigures. Of course, one has to watch out for the expansion problems. But to the best of my knowledge they do not get word with `groupplots`.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the units of time at a fixed place in the screen? As I animate and the time increases then the units jump left and right as the size of the number change.

Comment: @DanielDuque I'd like to ask you to ask a separate question on this, in which you show us the details how you animate the plots. From the comment alone I do not know, and I think that the original question should not be changed because as it is it is useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

One can achieve the same effect as a group plot using a tabular.  Note that I aligned the centers vertically in the first row and the bottoms of the axes in the second row.

The `[trim axis left]` option will align the left sides of the axes between rows, although it may require additional spacing to prevent overlaps.  `[trim axis right]` allows the plots to move closer together.  Pgfplots reserves space for annotation whether it is used on not.  See the [scale only axis] key.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\null\vfil
    \begin{figure}
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \hspace{1em}\parbox[c][2cm][s]{3cm}{\scriptsize
            $t=0$~s.
            \par\vfill
            $r=0$~m.
            \par\vfill
            $585$ macro-particles.
            \par\vfill
            $\overline{T} = 152.4$~K.} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left, trim axis right,
            width = 5cm,
            ylabel near ticks, 
            yticklabel pos=right,
            ylabel = {\tiny Particle Density~[m$^{-3}$]},
            xtick=\empty,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 77162484572430.92,
            xmin = 0.03157490368073539,
            xmax = 0.03653007600471181,
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            ]
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} \\
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left, trim axis right,
            width = 5cm,
            ytick=\empty,
            xlabel = {\tiny Probability Density},
            ymin = -217828.00503348646,
            ymax = 213540.67299828946,
            xmax = 1.1333435035653558e-05,
            xmin = 0,
            x dir = reverse,
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            ]
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} &
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.south)]
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left, trim axis right,
            width = 5cm,
            ylabel near ticks, 
            yticklabel pos=right,
            ylabel = {\tiny Speed~[m/s]},
            xlabel = {\tiny $z$~[m]},
            xmin = 0.03157490368073539,
            xmax = 0.03653007600471181,
            ymin = -217828.00503348646,
            ymax = 213540.67299828946,
            ticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            ]
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]